# How to print variable which contains another 2 variable with the select statement in sql

Tags: sql, variables

For example, based on the person's ID, get a sentence:

My name is (name), and I live in the (country)

Here is the code I wrote:

```
DECLARE @ID int, @name varchar(50),@country varchar(50)
SET @ID = 15
SET @name = 'SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE ID =' + CAST(@ID AS varchar(50))
SET @country = 'SELECT country FROM table2 WHERE ID =' + CAST(@ID as varchar(50))
```

Then I do not know what to do to replace the (name) and (country) in the sentence of

My name is (name), and I live in the (country)

Thank you.

Comment: What DBMS do you use? [Edit] the question and add the right tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace()`:

```
select replace(replace('My name is [name], and I live in the [country]',
                       '[name]', t1.name
                      ), '[country]', t2.country
              ) as sentence
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id = @id;
```

Note that dynamic SQL (i.e. putting the query in a string) is not needed for this at all.